# Serialize entity class containing IMongoQuery

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

My entity class is like this:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IMongoQuery MyQuery { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to persist this with the default serializers, when MyQuery contains anything complex such as an $in.

BsonDocumentSerializer gives error:

```
 Element name '$in' is not valid because it starts with a '$'.
```

I assume I need a special serializer type attributed to MyQuery. I've tried BsonDocument, BsonString, BsonJavaScript  - all cannont cast to MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument, which is the type of object stored in MyQuery.

Does this require a custom IBsonSerializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.  Stores the query as a JSON string.

```
public class QueryDocumentSerializer : BsonBaseSerializer
    {
        public override object Deserialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            if (bsonReader.GetCurrentBsonType() == BsonType.Null)
            {
                bsonReader.ReadNull();
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                var value = bsonReader.ReadString();
                var doc = BsonDocument.Parse(value);
                var query = new QueryDocument(doc);
                return query;
            }
        }

        public override void Serialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                bsonWriter.WriteNull();
            }
            else
            {
                var query = (QueryDocument)value;
                var json = query.ToJson();
                bsonWriter.WriteString(json);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for C# driver 2.0:

```
public class MyIMongoSerializer : SerializerBase<IMongoQuery>
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context,
                                   BsonSerializationArgs args,
                                   IMongoQuery value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            context.Writer.WriteNull();
        }
        else
        {
            var query = (IMongoQuery)value;
            var json = query.ToJson();
            context.Writer.WriteString(json);
        }
    }

    public override IMongoQuery Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context,
                                            BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context.Reader.GetCurrentBsonType() == BsonType.Null)
        {
            context.Reader.ReadNull();
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var value = context.Reader.ReadString();
            var doc = BsonDocument.Parse(value);
            var query = new QueryDocument(doc);
            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

And annotate the property to use the serializer:

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(MyIMongoSerializer))]
public IMongoQuery filter { get; set; }
```